# Splunk is conflicting with GMSServices

Tags: conflict, splunk, gmsplace

splunk is conflicting with GMSServices which make app crash. if i start splunk session GMSPicker crash the application and shows.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

     Mint.sharedInstance().initAndStartSession("XXXX");
     GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XXXX");

}
```

> -[SplunkNSURLSessionDataDelegateInterceptor setSession:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2f30e4380

Answer (score 9):

Only Google could solve this problem by overriding respondsToSelector to return whether the target responds to delegate selector.

You can work around. Disable network monitoring before initializing the SDK.

[[Mint SharedInstance] disableNetworkMonitoring];

for swift

```
Mint.sharedInstance().disableNetworkMonitoring()
Mint.sharedInstance().initAndStartSessionWithAPIKey(XXXXX)
```